# How exactly do you pitch in Major League Baseball 2k10?

Tags: mlb-2k10

While pitching, we get A B C D on the left side to choose the kind of ball to deliver. So I press the corresponding button on the PC keyboard, and no matter which numpad button I tap, the pitcher always throws crooked. Sometimes it seems like he's throwing correctly and the ball is going where it should, but still he gets scored "ball."

So any idea how you can pitch in *Major League Baseball 2k10*?